# Scrapy - order of crawled urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got an issue with scrapy and python.
I have several links. I crawl data from each of them in one script with the use of loop. But the order of crawled data is random or at least doesn't match to the link.

So I can't match url of each subpage with the outputed data.

Like: crawled url, data1, data2, data3.
Data 1, data2, data3 => It's ok, because it comes from one loop, but how can I add to the loop current url or can I set the order of link's list? Like first from the list is crawled as first, second is crawled as second...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make scrapy follow links in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227302/make-scrapy-follow-links-in-order)

Comment: Could you provide us with some part of your code so we might understand where the issue lies ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class sth(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sth'
    allowed_domain = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [ 
         'https://www.example.com/url1/',
         'https://www.example.com/url2/',
         'https://www.example.com/url3/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
          for content in response.css('div#content'):
               yield {
                    'data1': content.css('li#name2::text').extract(),
                    'data2': content.css('li#name1::text').extract(),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep() - would it be a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, It seems that the solution is in settings.py file in scrapy.

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3

Between requests.

It should be uncommented. Defaultly it's commented.

Comment: This is not the proper solution, it only seems to resolve your "problem". Scrapy is async, which means you can't count on order of responses incoming, that depens on the network speed (IO). If you must have sequential downloads, you will need to maintain a stack yourself and pop from it only after you receive the response from the last request. But I'm pretty sure you don't need that, as you can simply attach the URL to the item iteself: `yield{ 'url': response.url, ...}`.